# Pentaho 5.3: access datasource from index.jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, pentaho

I am a newbie to Pentaho and try to make an `alert(some_msg_from_datasource)` in the index.jsp of Pentaho. But I cannot figure out how to access the Pentaho variables from here. This is what I have

```
<head> ...  <script type="text/javascript">
        var Home = null;
        pen.require(["home/home",
          "common-ui/util/ContextProvider"], function(pentahoHome, ContextProvider) {
          Home = pentahoHome;

          // Define properties for loading context
          var contextConfig = [{
            path: "properties/config",
            post: function(context, loadedMap) {
              context.config = loadedMap;
            }
          }, {
            path: "properties/messages",
            post: function(context, loadedMap) {
              context.i18n = loadedMap;
            }
          }];

          // Define permissions
          ContextProvider.addProperty("canCreateContent", <%=canCreateContent%>);
          ContextProvider.addProperty("hasAnalyzerPlugin", <%=pluginIds.contains("analyzer")%>);
          ContextProvider.addProperty("hasDataAccess", false); // default

          // BISERVER-8631 - Manage datasources only available to roles/users with appropriate permissions
          var serviceUrl = Home.getUrlBase() + "plugin/data-access/api/permissions/hasDataAccess";
          Home.getContent(serviceUrl, function(result) {
            ContextProvider.addProperty("hasDataAccess", result);
            ContextProvider.get(Home.init, contextConfig); // initialize
          }, function(error) {
            console.log(error);
            ContextProvider.get(Home.init, contextConfig); // log error and initialize anyway
          });

        });
      </script>  </head>
```

And for the body:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".sidebar" onload="onBodyLoad()">
<script>
function onBodyLoad(){
  alert("MOTD: " + the_motd_from_a_pentaho_var);
}
</script>
```

I assume I need the webcontext but I don't understand the head-scripts and how I can make it run. Tbh I don't even fully understand the syntax in the head. Please help :(

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you intend to do. As for the syntax in the head, it's a jsp. I assume that you(re familiar with it.

Comment: most of it is the standard pentaho stuff which I didn't write myself. I want to access a value generated by a pentaho datasource and show this in a popup window on the index.jsp. While doing this IN pentaho poses no problem, doing so on the index.jsp is something different as I cannot refer the pentaho variables